# For which values of $a,b $ the ring $Q[t^a,t^b]$ would be UFD

Tags: ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

We know that $Q[t^2,t^3]$ is not UFD as
$t^6$ had two different factorization. But I am not sure in general how to find $a,b$ for which $Q[t^a,t^b]$ would be UFD.

Comment: Won't $t^{ab}$ have two factorizations for the same reason when ...?

Comment: Having two factorisations isn't the issue. $\Bbb Z$ is an UFD, yet $12=3\cdot 4=2\cdot 6$ has two different factorisations. You have to be more specific about what the exact condition is.

Comment: Yes but here 3 divides 6 or 2 divides 4 but this is not the case for Q[t^2,t^3]

Comment: So what is the exact notion of "unique factorisation" that UFD refers to? Without having that really clearly in your head, you have no hope of finding the answer.